# Selenium: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element

Tags: selenium

I have a testcase which is running fine in my local Windows system, but after uploading it into my Linux server, its showing following error:

Basically my testcase is First doing login which is working fine, in login page also i have used `id`attribute.  After successfully login it goes to  `Load User list` page which basically contain a huge amount of table rows and one form at the top which has many textfield .
On the same `Load User list` page, i am trying to read the textbox Id attribute but its showing error as displayed below:  Why am not able to read id attribute  for this page ? But as i already said the same testcase is running perfectly from localsystem

```
Testcase: campaignEmailTestCase took 108.276 sec
            Caused an ERROR
    Timed out after 100 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName
    Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
    System info: host: 'smart-systems-pro-2', ip: '10.180.31.90', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-5-xen-amd64', java.version: '1.6.0_18'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 100 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: leadCaptureList_leadCapture_firstName
    Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
    System info: host: 'smart-systems-pro-2', ip: '10.180.31.90', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-5-xen-amd64', java.version: '1.6.0_18'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
             ............
             ............
             .............    

  [1]: http://www.danstraw.com/installing-selenium-server-2-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/2010/09/23/
```

I have even tried with giving 990 secs timeout, but also same issue.  What could be the reason?

I refereed [this website for installing selenium in my server](http://www.danstraw.com/installing-selenium-server-2-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/2010/09/23/)  My selenium jar is `selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar`

Comment: why -v vote?  Please write comment

Comment: Hello guys, i have described my question clearly now in order to solve this Off-topic reason(it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem)  ..Hope now you can help me with this one

Comment: Please help me, struggling since 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means the element you are trying to use is not visible.

You'll want to check that `visibility` is not set to hidden.

It will also need to have `height` and/or `width` set to greater than zero

Comment: What does it mean `It will also need to have height and/or width set to greater than zero` ?? Can you edit your question? Same code if i run from my local Windows system then its working fine. But while running in linux server showing above error...

Answer (score 0):

ExpectedConditions were introduced in `v2.6.0`, which is some months newer than the version that you are using. Your version `selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar` dates back to year 2010 or so. I suggest switching to current version of selenium and check if the error persists. [You can get v2.40 here.](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar)

Comment: I am testing with latest jar... please wait

Comment: still the same issue..